# Exercício de construção de potência em C

Tags: c

Estou começando a aprender a programar, então me desculpem qualquer erro mais bobo. É um exercício simples, fazer uma potência em C colocando a base e o exponencial. Aqui tá o meu código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int n = 0;
    float x = 0;
    int k = 1;
    float s = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%f", &x);

    do{
        if(k!=n){
            k = k + 1; 
            s = x*x + s;
        }
        else { s = x;
        }
    } while( k != n); 

    printf("%f", s);

return 0;

}
```

Questão é que por algum motivo, a partir da segunda operação ele multiplica o X como um número inteiro, exemplo:

2,1^3: Ele deveria me dar 2,1*2,1*2,1 = 9,26

Ao invés disso ele me dá 2,1*2,1*2 = 8,82

Alguém tem alguma ideia do porquê disso e como corrigir?

Comment: Creio que seu algoritmo está errado. Você está fazendo um somatório de x^2.

Comment: Uma alternativa é: `float s=1;` e substituir seu loop por: `for (k=1; k<=n; k++) s *= x;`.

Comment: por que não usar [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na variável `s`, você deveria estar multiplicando `x` e não `x*x`. Além disso, não deveria estar somando nada (aquele `+ s`).

Aqui vai o seu programa revisado. Também funciona para potências inteiras negativas:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    float x = 0;
    int k = 1;
    float s = 1.0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%f", &x);

    if (n > 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            s *= x;
        }
    } else if (n < 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < -n; k++) {
            s /= x;
        }
    }

    printf("%f", s);

    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/gcLftd)

Caso não saiba, o `s *= x` equivale a `s = s * x`, o `s /= x` equivale a `s = s / x` e  o `k++` equivale a `k = k + 1`. O uso do `for` equivale ao do `while` neste contexto, e uma vez que seja entendido, é mais simples de avaliar mentalmente quanto a sua corretude.